# Using System.ComponentModel.DisplayName with dynamic values?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, system.componentmodel

Im trying to implement multi-language support in my system, 
the other systems at work uses xmlfiles for this generated from a database that they have used for some time now so they want me to use this aswell.

I have managed to translate everything except the displaynames in my formmodels, these values can apperantly only be constant values so i can't use a method that gets the correct translation.

This is how the code is now:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DisplayName("Kontraktnamn")]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

And i want to do something like this:

```
[System.ComponentModel.DisplayName(GetTextByKey("Contract_Name"))]
public string Name { get; set; }
```

Is it possible to work around this? Or maybe there is a better way to do it and still use the xmlfiles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create your own custom attribute that can read the xml values:

```
public class CustomDisplayName : DisplayNameAttribute
{
    public CustomDisplayName()
    {
        this.DisplayName = MyXmlReader.Read(DisplayName);
    }
}
```

Comment: Did not compile on my system, because setting DisplayName was not possible. But you can do this
`public CustomDisplayName(aDisplayName)
 : base(aDisplayName)
{}
    override string DisplayName { get { return MyXmlReader.Read(base.DisplayName); } }`